# How to pass context between Virtual Assistant and Skill

Tags: botframework

I'm building Virtual Assistant based on template (https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions). 
I wonder how could I pass context from Virtual Assistant into Skill? Let say I got some responses from user when conversation was on Virtual Assistant level, now I need to trigger skill and I need state from assistant to be accessible in skill.

I trigger skill using -> `await dc.BeginDialogAsync(identifiedSkill.Id);` 
Skill dialog is build on `RouterDialog` class. I could override method `OnBeginDialogAsync` to make use of option parameter (right now it doesn't use this parameter at all), but I wonder if there is any other way to pass context/state.

Regards

Comment: What skill are you trying to send context to? And, for what purpose?